# Pass rows from Excel file to stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, excel, etl

I need help with SQL query that would load data from Excel and pass them to stored procedure. Excel file contains 4 columns and 50k+ rows, while stored procedure expects 4 parameters. How can I iterate through Excel file row by row and pass this data to the stored procedure? I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Google SSIS Excel

Comment: Create a table, insert your excel data inside it, then run a cursor on the table's rows. One of the rare cases a cursor is not to be avoided.

Comment: There are numerous ways to import the data - if that's you're issue? Eg [openrowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or with SQL2019+ ODBC and Polybase

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I think I will try SSIS option using OLE DB Command which executes SQL command for each row in the Data Flow. In my case it would be a parameterized call to stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to run a SProc in SQL Server, and control it from Excel. See the code example below for details on how to do this.

```
Sub RunSProc()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=your_server_name;"
strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=your_database_name;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

cn.Open strConn

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "MyOrders"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Text
Set rs = cmd.Execute()

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A5:D500").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
End If

End Sub
```

[image]